# Firebase services not working on Emulator after update to version 31.3.10

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, android-emulator

After emulator version update I'm not able to sign in with Firebase Google/anonymous or to use firestore.

Network type full/great.

**Update:**
It is looks like the connection with firebase is very slow, take about 5 minutes to sign in, and the data is fetched very slow, however internet in emulator browser work just fine.

On real device everything works well.

Same happen on 2 machines on different networks.

Someone familiar?

**Solved:**
Downgrading emulator version to `31.2.9`

Comment: What's the Android Version are you using?

Comment: Android version on emulator? tired multiple 30,29,27

Comment: Yeah. I am not sure what could have caused the issue then. From the SDK Manager, can you please check the emulator version as well?

Comment: Is there an error that you get, when you try to sign in?

Comment: Downgrading emulator version to `31.2.9` solved this issue, interesting that from emulator archive emulator version `31.3.10` is in beta, and I'm not subscribed to beta channel..

Comment: based on the votes the issue effecting many users

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try downgrading the android emulator version to **31.2.9**

This worked for me.

Use this link to downgrade - https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Answer (score 3):

Emulator Version `31.3.12` contains a fix for this issue.

Comment: Out of interest, how did you know this, @pavel-poley? (I ask because I saw the update in Studio but release notes https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator don't have this release listed yet at time of writing.) Is there a repo with a changelog somewhere?

Comment: update available in the sdk manager

Comment: I doubt it contains a fix as I am still facing this issue. Letting the emulator run while reading SO it managed to connect to firebase services. Took the emulator 5 attempts and 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Last Android Emulator **34.1.18** with Android Studio Iguana **2023.2.1** works perfectly.

I was running Emulator version 31.3.10 with Android Studio 2023.1.1 and it wasnt working.