# Firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword suspends forever

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with Firebase authentication on one of my development machines.
The following code is used for authentication:

```
fun onSignIn() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        authenticate(email, password)
    }
}

suspend fun authenticate(email: String, password: String) {
    Firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
}
```

Everything works fine on my macOS Big Sur, but the authenticate function suspends forever on my Windows 10 machine.
Both machines run the same code, the same emulator - a Pixel 4 API 30, and have identical *google-services.json* file.

I have also tried without suspending but to no avail:

```
Firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { 
    Log.i(TAG, "on complete")  // This is never reached on the windows machine
}
```

I see no errors in the logs.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a failure listener as well, to see if something fails?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add the OnFailureListener as well, but the callback is never invoked.

Comment: So you say neither onSuccess nor onFailure is triggered?

Comment: That is correct. But only on my windows machine…

Comment: Then are you sure your Windows machine is connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes, I can also browse internet on the emulator

Comment: And also fetch data from apis on the internet from inside the app

Comment: I solved my issue by downgrading the emulator as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73386258/firebase-services-not-working-on-emulator-after-update-to-version-31-3-10